# Oracle Webtier 12.2.1.1 on Windows startComponent.cmd "exit status = -1073741515"

Tags: windows, oracle

I am attempting to install Oracle HTTP server 12.2.1.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 in standalone mode.  I believe I followed the Oracle documentation correctly.  I have progressed to this point: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/WTINS/GUID-3ED8EE64-EE8B-4EF3-84A1-19CEF21B8547.htm#WTINS414

My attempts to run "startComponent.cmd ohs1" have resulted in this error:

```
weblogic.nodemanager.NMException: Received error message from Node Manager Serve
r: [Server start command for OHS server 'ohs1' failed due to: [Failed t
o start the server ohs1
```

The error message also says to check a log file.  Contents are:

```
<2016-06-29 15:42:10> <INFO> <OHS-4018> <Starting server ohs1>
<2016-06-29 15:42:10> <INFO> <OHS-0> <Running C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\ohs\bin\launch.exe C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\ohs\bin\httpd.exe -DOHS_MPM_WINNT -d C:/Middleware/Oracle_Home_12/user_projects/domains/base_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/ohs1 -f C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\instances\ohs1\httpd.conf>
<2016-06-29 15:42:11> <SEVERE> <OHS-0> <C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\ohs\bin\launch.exe C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\ohs\bin\httpd.exe -DOHS_MPM_WINNT -d C:/Middleware/Oracle_Home_12/user_projects/domains/base_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/ohs1 -f C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\instances\ohs1\httpd.conf: exit status = -1073741515>
<2016-06-29 15:42:11> <INFO> <OHS-4005> <Check the instance log file for more information: C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\ohs1\logs\ohs1.log>
<2016-06-29 15:42:11> <SEVERE> <OHS-0> <Failed to start the server ohs1>
```

The log file referenced here, "C:\Middleware\Oracle_Home_12\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\ohs1\logs\ohs1.log", does not exist.

I also made sure that the required Microsoft redistributable was installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I received help from the Oracle Community:

***Do you have lastinvocation.log file under
C:/Middleware/Oracle_Home_12/user_projects/domains\base_domain\servers\ohs1\logs?
If yes, rename it to lastinvocation.cmd and run this from command line and check if the ohs1.log file gets generated.
If yes, what is the error message seen?***

The error message returned was:

***"The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."***

The user then pointed me to an Oracle Doc:

***This is also described in the below article
Oracle HTTP Server 12.2.1 Fails To Start With Error 'MSVCR110.dll' Missing From Your Computer (Doc ID 2078713.1)***

This Oracle article had a link to a DIFFERENT (larger) version of vcredist_x64.exe than I had used when installing the components.  This version worked.

Thanks to Aishwarya in the Oracle community!

Comment: i used vcredist_x64.exe after dowloading. But still futile.  Do i need to restart my system?